# Function Update in Unity5 doesn't receive variable's value after function Start

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5. The set up is the following:

- A camera.
- A 3D plane and a canvas with 3 UI Buttons.
- A Script in c# attached to the camera. Such script contains only 2 functions:
  Start() and Update().

Here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ChangeButtonsText : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Menu;

    private Transform[] transforms;
    private List<string> texts;
    private int numButtons;
    private int menuIndex;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        texts = new List<string> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            texts.Add("I am the button number " + i.ToString());
        }
        int numButtons = Menu.transform.childCount;
        print ("1 numButtons = " + numButtons.ToString ());
        transforms = new Transform[numButtons];
        for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; ++i) {
            transforms[i] = Menu.transform.GetChild(i);
        }
        print ("2 numButtons = " + numButtons.ToString ());

        menuIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
            transforms[i].GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = texts[menuIndex];
            if((i < numButtons-1) && (menuIndex < texts.Count - 1)) menuIndex++;
        }
        print ("3 numButtons = " + numButtons.ToString ());


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        print ("4 numButtons = " + numButtons.ToString ());

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) {
            print ("5 numButtons = " + numButtons.ToString ());

            if (menuIndex < texts.Count - 1) menuIndex++;
            print (menuIndex.ToString());
            int j = 0;
            print ("6 numButtons = " + numButtons.ToString ());
            print ("Going in!");
            for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
                print ("I'm in!");
                transforms[i].GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = texts[menuIndex-j];
                print ("Changed!");
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The 3 firsts prints regarding numButtons show 3. However, the 4th print (the first on in the Update() function prints a 0.
Any idea why is this happening?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `Start()` method, you're declaring a new variable called `numButtons`, hiding the instance member with the same name. To fix it, simply remove the `int` before it, then it will assign the member and not the local variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    texts.Add("I am the button number " + i.ToString());
}
numButtons = Menu.transform.childCount; // no "int" here
print ("1 numButtons = " + numButtons.ToString ());
```

Comment: Oh... I cannot believe I did that mistake. Maybe I was too sleepy hahah
Okay, thank you very much!